# bootstrap @Configuration from subproject into app-context.xml

Tags: java, spring

I'm very new to spring to be nice ;)

I have a shared module i'll call "Core" and a couple of projects which depend upon core. The sub-projects have `spring/app-context.xml` files and in the environment they are executed in, spring is initailised by another framework.

In the "core" project I'd like to use the @Configuration method of defining some singleton services:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig
{
    @Bean
    public MyService myService()
    {
        return new MyServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

Core is then packaged in a jar, and included on the sub-project's classpath.

How to I bootstrap the core module's services so that they are available for @Autowire in the subprojects?

**EDIT:**

The error I run into is:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   matching bean of type [package.MyService] found for dependency:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I've tried each of the following (exclusively):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="package" />
<import resource="classpath*:spring/core-context.xml" /><!-- defined in core.jar with MyService as a bean -->
<bean class="package.AppConfig" />
```

but only adding this to the subproject's app-context.xml seems to resolve the error:

```
<bean id="MyService" class="package.MyServiceImpl" />
```

Comment: ... or I'm not entirely tied to using @Configuration method, but I MUST be able to configure beans/services within the core module without having to re-configure them in the sub-projects

Comment: Have you taken a look at the log4j logs?  In DEBUG level logging, you should be able to see some more information around why it is finding `AppConfig` and not `MyService`.

Comment: hi nicholas, thanks for the tips. turning up the spring logs i can see that the platform is throwing a ClassNotFound on my AppConfig, meaning the container hasn't loaded the full classpath for the module before initialising the spring app-context. I will have to take this up with the vendor of the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [JavaDoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html), it says it all:

> ***Via Spring  XML***
>
> As an alternative to registering @Configuration classes directly against an AnnotationConfigApplicationContext, @Configuration classes may be declared as normal  definitions within Spring XML files:

```
<beans>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean class="com.acme.AppConfig"/>
</beans>
```

It sounds like simply including the `@Configuration` class as a bean into your xml config will pick it up.

Beyond that, you should also be able to pick up the class via `component-scan`, as `@Configuration` has a meta-annotation of `@Component`.

Comment: Well, that is straight out of the documentation, so I think it should work.  What about it didn't work?  Did you get an exception?  Is your classpath setup properly?  Also, I am not seeing an edit.